# Single-phase voltage inverter

Tags: transistors, mosfet, load, single-phase

I'm currently working on a single-phase voltage inverter with MOSFET transistors and RL load. I would like to realize width control of the inverter with independent frequency and program settings angle. Turn ON signal will be with MOSFET M1 + M4 and turn OFF will be with M2 + M3. DC. The supply voltage will be 100 V DC. How can I calculate RL load values so that ampere units will flow through it? I set 100 us turn ON signal and 200 us turn OFF signal so the duty cycle should be 50%. The period is set for 300.15us (150 ns for dead zone time of MOSFET).

[image: Schematic]
[image: Simulation]

Comment: Could you probe the voltage on M1 to M4? Since all gates are connected directly to ground, I would assume that all MOSFETs are not driven and you see some simulation jitter on I(L1). Also look into driving P- and N-MOS, they are not driven the same way!

Comment: You've shorted all your gates to ground, so none of the FETs are ever going to turn on.

Comment: @Hearth without grounding the gates, I wont be able to turn ON the simulation...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Grounding all your gates forces every MOSFET off, regardless of what you do anywhere else.

Comment: @Hearth I have Vpulse in every MOSFET gate circuit and OrCAD doesn't let me start the simulation without grounding this Vpulse supply..

Comment: @Simplifier You need to connect the negative of the supply somewhere, sure. You don't need to connect it to ground, and you *definitely* don't need to connect the supply negative to the gate!

Answer (score 0):

Start with simpler simulation is my suggestion.

- Use a single MOSFET (configured as M1)
- Drive a resistive load directly connected between source and ground
- Don't use the unfeasibly large looking inductor
- Simulate to debug why your method of driving high-side MOSFETs will not work

**Hint**: to drive a MOSFET you need to apply the drive voltage between gate and source and not between gate and 0 volts (as you have in your schematic). It works for the low-side MOSFETs but will not work correctly for high-side MOSFETs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your V3, V4 gate drive signals to connect between source and gate. By grounding them, you make a very strange circuit.